# Assist with Js object constructor

Tags: javascript

I am working on an javascript app and having some trouble with the object constructor.  I am going to make each card in the deck an object and so just working on building an array of those objects.  Here is what i have :

```js
    function card(suit1,number1) // Constructor
    {
    this.suit1 = suit1;
    this.number1 = number1;
    }


    function makeDeck1() {
    var deck1 = new Array()
  
    deck1[0]= new card('S','A');
    deck1[1]= new card('S','1');

    }


    function myFunction() {
 makeDeck1();
    alert('gman' + deck1); 
    }
```

```html
    <h2>Blackjack</h2>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

basically the console is telling me that "deck1" is not defined...so something is wrong with the process...

was wondering if anyone can shed any light on this.

Thanks!  G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console is giving correct error as `deck1` doesn't exist inside `myFunction()`, it was declared inside `makeDeck1()` and its scope is limited to this function, you need to return it and assign to a variable inside `myFunction()` to be able to use it.

```js
function card(suit1, number1) {
  this.suit1 = suit1;
  this.number1 = number1;
}


function makeDeck1() {
  var deck1 = []; // avoid new Array constructor
  deck1.push(new card('S', 'A'));
  deck1.push(new card('S', '1'));
  return deck1;
}

function myFunction() {
  var deck1 = makeDeck1();
  alert('gman' + JSON.stringify(deck1));
  console.log(deck1);
}
```

```html
<h2>Blackjack</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for everyones help as I am working hard on mastering Javascript.  I have made a lot of progress in the last 30 days but obviously still need some learning on scope and objects etc....

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use a class like you did with card? (P.S. Classes should start with an uppercase letter).

```js
function Card(suit, number) {
  this.suit = suit;
  this.number = number;
}

Card.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.suit + this.number;
};


function Deck() {
  this.deck = [new Card('S', 'A'), new Card('S', '1')];
}

Deck.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.deck.join(",");
};


function myFunction() {
  var deck = new Deck;
  console.log('gman:' + deck);
}
```

```html
<h2>Blackjack</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for everyones help as I am working hard on mastering Javascript.  I have made a lot of progress in the last 30 days but obviously still need some learning on scope and objects etc....

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Please don't upvote this, since it's a trivial answer, just being helpful</sub>

The problem is that your variable only exists in the scope of `makeDeck1()`. You need to return the value like so:

```js
function card(suit1, number1) // Constructor
{
  this.suit1 = suit1;
  this.number1 = number1;
}


function makeDeck1() {
  var deck1 = new Array()

  deck1[0] = new card('S', 'A');
  deck1[1] = new card('S', '1');

  return deck1; // return it
}


function myFunction() {
  var deck1 = makeDeck1(); // define it here
  alert('gman ' + JSON.stringify(deck1)); // serialize it
}
```

```html
<h2>Blackjack</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

In addition, it is conventional to define constructors using title-case, so `Card` instead of `card`. Good luck.

Comment: *Please don't upvote this, since it's a trivial answer, just being helpful* => upvote ;)